# Firebase Query providing different results with addListenerForSingleValueEvent and addChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my query where I try to sort a node with the given constraints

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("chat")
            .child("room-messages")
            .child(roomID)
            .orderByChild("timestamp")
            .limitToLast(index);
```

Now the problem I'm facing is when I add a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` it gives me wrong sort order of the nodes but works fine with `addChildEventListener`.

Is this some kind of bug in Firebase or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you please add an example for both sorts?